# Jquery - I Need One Function to Run Before Another (not at same time)

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I have two jquery functions that I would like to run when a form is submitted.  I need one function to run and complete before the next function begins.  The first functions runs ajax to check the db and then returns a value.  I do not wank the second function to run until the first functions is completely finished (ajax).  I know that js is asynchronous and runs all at the same time, but is there a way to stop all functions from running until the first function is complete? In short, my form is submitting before the ajax runs the db check for duplicate values.  So i need it to run function 1 first to check for duplicates, then run function 2 to finish the validation before submitting.

```
function f1(){
   ...ajax
}
function f2(){
  ...
}

$(function() {

    $("#MyForm").submit(function(){
        f1();
        f2();
        return false            
    })
})
```

Comment: JavaScript is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're using Jquery ajax, you can run the second function in the success block**

```
$("#MyForm").submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
    .
    .
    success:function(response) { f2(); }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the AJAX [promise](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in f1 as follows and then use [.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
function f1(){
   return $.ajax(/***/);//return the deferred
}
function f2(){
  ...
}

$(function() {
    $("#MyForm").submit(function(){
        f1()
        .then(f2);
        return false            
    })
})
```

If you're interested you may want to read a little about promises on [promisejs.org](http://www.promisejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

in the success part of your ajax call in function1 just call function2

function f1(){
   ...ajax
   f2()
}
function f2(){
  ...
}

$(function() {

```
$("#MyForm").submit(function(){
    f1();
    return false            
})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

sorry for wrong interpreation

```
function f1()
{
$.post('url','data',function(res){

f2();
})

}
function f2{

}
```

may be this one helps.

Comment: Updated my answer my with my apology.